# usage memory with widget.destroy()

Tags: python, tkinter, optimization, memory-management

first of all, sorry for my english communication skills, I am learning it. I have a little question about the widget.destroy() in Tkinter. I read that if you want destroy a widget, **destroy = remove from memory because you are not going to reuse**, you should use this function. But **I am using and they are not removed from the memory**, **I saw it when I create news widgets and appear with the next numbers**.

My code create only 10 differents buttons and, like you can see in the screenshots, I have 20 buttons. This is because I make twice click in the button. My question is not how I can remove/hide and create/show it,**my question is for the usage memory and make it optimized.** I want understand the logic behind it.

This is my code, it is not perfect but it's a little test, with some screenshots:

```
import tkinter as tk
from utils.geometrIrregular import FigurasGeometricas_irregulares

minpady = 10
minpadx = 10

class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__( self):
        super().__init__()
        # Menu Buttons
        tk.Button( self, text = "Geometria",
                        command = lambda: self.center_geometry(),
                        width = 10, height = 5, name = 'geometria'
                        ).place( relx = .01, rely = .2)
        tk.Button( self, text = "Calculadora",
                             command = lambda: self.center_calculate(),
                             width = 10, height = 5, name = 'calculadora'
                             ).place( relx = .01, rely = .4)      
        
    def center_geometry( self) -> None:
        self.clean_frame()
        tk.Label( self, text = "Inserta las coordenadas: "
                               ).place( relx = .12, rely = .1)
        
        tk.Entry( self,
                 ).place( relx = .23, rely = .1)
        """ bind options:
            FocusIn, FocusOut, <Button-1>, <KeyPress>... -> some options
        """        
        tk.Button( self, text = "Crear polinomio"
                  ).place( relx = .2, rely = .15)        
             
    def center_calculate( self) -> None:
        """ we are going to create the tk.widgets in the central part
        """
        self.clean_frame()
        self.memory_lst = []
        self.calculate_history = tk.StringVar()
        self.value = tk.StringVar()
        self.result = tk.StringVar()
        self.memory = tk.StringVar()
        
        tk.Label( self,
                 text = 'Last operation:'
                 ).place( relx = .2, rely = .1)
        tk.Entry( self,
                background = 'light grey',
                textvariable = self.calculate_history
                ).place( relx = .25, rely = .1)
        
        tk.Label( self,
                 text = 'Result:'
                ).place( relx = .2, rely = .15)
        tk.Label( self,
                 background = 'snow',
                 textvariable = self.result
                ).place( relx = .25, rely = .15)
        
        tk.Label( self,
                 text = 'Operation:'
                ).place( relx = .20, rely = .2)
        tk.Entry( self,
                 background = 'white',
                 textvariable = self.value
                ).place( relx = .25, rely = .2)
        
        # First buttons row
        tk.Button( self, text = " + "
                  ).place( relx = .25, rely = .25)
        tk.Button( self, text = " - "
                  ).place( relx = .27, rely = .25)
        tk.Button( self, text = " / "
                  ).place( relx = .29, rely = .25)
        tk.Button( self, text = " * "
                  ).place( relx = .31, rely = .25)
        
        # Second buttons row
        tk.Button( self, text = 'M+'
                            ).place( relx = .25, rely = .28)
        tk.Button( self, text = 'M'
                            ).place( relx = .27, rely = .28)
        tk.Button( self, text = 'M-'
                            ).place( relx = .29, rely = .28)
        tk.Button( self, text = ' ^ '
                            ).place( relx = .31, rely = .28)
        
        # Thrid buttons row
        tk.Button( self, text = ' √ '
                            ).place( relx = .25, rely = .31)
        # Memory Lst_Box
        self.memory_lstbox = tk.Listbox( self, background = 'white', listvariable = self.memory,
                              width = 50, height = 50, selectmode = tk.SINGLE
                              ).place( relx = .6, rely = .1)
    # CLEAN BLOCK
    def clean_frame( self):
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            print( widget.winfo_id)
            if not ('geometria' in str(widget) or 'calculadora' in str(widget)):
                widget.destroy()
                
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = Root()
    App.mainloop()
```

```
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .geometria>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .calculadora>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .geometria>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .calculadora>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label2>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label3>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label4>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry2>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button2>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button3>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button4>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button5>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button6>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button7>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button8>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button9>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Listbox object .!listbox>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .geometria>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .calculadora>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label5>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry3>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button10>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .geometria>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .calculadora>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label6>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry4>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label7>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label8>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label9>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry5>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button11>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button12>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button13>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button14>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button15>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button16>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button17>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button18>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button19>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Listbox object .!listbox2>>
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the amount of code in your question. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, we probably don't need all the functionality of the math operations. Please provide just enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: OK, sorry, I am going to edit it and create a minimal example.

Comment: Now I shorten the code and set the destroy. I was changing somethings and I don't remember to set it again hahaha. The destroy is in the last function named **clean_frame**

Comment: I do it! Thank you for the tips :) it's my first or second post it

Comment: No problem :), is this the output you got from your current code?

Comment: Yeah! If you click in the both buttons, you are going to take this output.

Comment: Notice that you're printing the _method_, not the _results_ of the method. If you want to see the id, you should print `widget.winfo_id()` (note the trailing `()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only prints things in the `clean_frame` function. Every time the function is called it prints the `root`'s content.

Your output looks like that not because the `.destroy()` isn't working properly, but because the function is printing at the end of your output (where the last function finished printing) resulting a really long list.

I only printed the the number of widgets in the root (in the beginning of your `clean_frame` function) so the output would be more readable and so you could follow the widgets in your app.

You received that many widgets in your output because you didn't format the output at all, so the output is from all the clicking you have made.

#### The modified function:

```python
    def clean_frame( self):
        print(len(self.winfo_children()))
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            print( widget.winfo_id)
            if not ('geometria' in str(widget) or 'calculadora' in str(widget)):
                widget.destroy()
```

##### This is what my output looks like:

```
2
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .geometria>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .calculadora>>
18
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .geometria>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .calculadora>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label2>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label3>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label4>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry2>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button2>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button3>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button4>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button5>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button6>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button7>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button8>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button9>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Listbox object .!listbox>>
5
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .geometria>>  
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .calculadora>>
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Label object .!label5>>     
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry3>>     
<bound method Misc.winfo_id of <tkinter.Button object .!button10>>  
18
...
```

---

The reason you are seeing the id keep going up is because `tkinter` won't create the same id twice.

`tkinter` doesn't reuse the `ID` of a destroyed object for a new one. Instead, it generates a new, unique `ID`.

Comment: I have a question about the memory, the buttons are remove from the memory but why the ID number is not reset?

Comment: Hi, please look at the edit in the bottom.. :)

Comment: last question hahaha is that happend because use C library? Because in some languages, like Rust or C, the variables are unique and can't create twice. Thank you soo much for all Nokla!

Comment: @HombreconNombre I think It's more about how `tkinter` implementation manages widgets and their IDs.

Comment: I think that the both are correct. :) https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

Comment: @nokla The id of a widget (what is returned by `winfo_id()` is assigned by the window manager. The name of the widget (eg `"button10"` is assigned by `tkinter` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/232465204edb070751f4794c67dd31cd9b7c8c53/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2682)